# Android Media player get duration for streaming track is larger than its original value

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

While streaming the online songs in android in built media player, when i am trying to fetch the total duration with mediaplayer.getDuration(); it is giving me 443:13:56 as total duration whereas the original duration of that song is 3:05. I am not able to trace why I am facing this problem? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by myself, it was happening because of the slow internet connection. Media player was not able to extract the original size of song, so it was showing a garbage value.